# How do I retrieve a modules path when I have a class from that module

Tags: python

In python, If I have a class `foo`, I can `call foo.__module__` to get a string with the name of the module it is part of.

If I have a module `bar`, I can call `bar.__file__` to get a string with the path where the module was loaded from.

How, when I only have class foo can I get the path of the module it is part of? (`foo.__module__` returns a string, not an instance of the module it names)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sys.modules` is a mapping from module name to module:

```
sys.modules[foo.__module__].__file__
```

Answer (score 3):

For such introspection tasks, I always recommend using Python standard library's `inspect` module: it can handle some corner cases &c and makes the whole process much smoother.  For your specific task, [inspect.getsourcefile](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html?highlight=getsourcefile#inspect.getsourcefile) can be handy -- e.g., consider...:

```
>>> from sched import scheduler as someclass
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getsourcefile(someclass)
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/sched.py'
```

this always tries to give you the `.py` file rather than sometimes the `.py` file and sometimes a `.pyc` file instead -- not a big deal, but one more useful "regularity".